# swift wkwebview is blank page after login

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I add wkwebview to load login page :

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.uiDelegate = self 
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view = webView
}
```

and load page with :

```
let myURL = URL(string: strUrl)
let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
self.webView.load(myRequest)
```

It loaded login page is successful but after logged page is blank ? 
I sure that, logged page vie ok on web.

Comment: is any error you getting?

Comment: No...not error. I use this function, it printed "Finish"
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Finish")
    }

Comment: can you share url ?

Comment: @Ruchi Makadia Sry, it is local.

Comment: @RyanTran check your frame is .zero. may be because of that. Give a frame like self.view.frame.

Comment: After working with server side, system is ok on web, this means system still able to login success on web. But on my ios app, after login, wkwebview is blank ?